# How to remove backslashes in a string

Tags: c#

I get a string from a website called "willekeurigwoord.nl" which means random word. So when I get the string from the site with HtmlAgilityPack, it is formatted like "\n\t\t\tkegelvrucht\r\n \t\n\t\t".

So the word that I get is "kegelvrucht" but before and after the word there are backslashes which when I try to remove they get ignored even when I put "@" or use double backslashes ("\") in front of the string.

So my question is, how do I remove the \ in my string?

I did try everything that is in the comment lines.

```
    private string RandomWordOnline() //Get the word online
    {
        //get string from htlm file with htmlagilitypack
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = webGet.Load("http://www.willekeurigwoord.nl/");
        String word = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1").InnerText;

        //word = word.Replace(@"\", "");            
        //word = @word.Trim(new char[] {' ','\\'});
        //word = word.Substring(8, word.Length - 13);
        //word = word.Substring(0, 13);

        //trying to remove backslash, does not work
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {

            char chrWord = Convert.ToChar(word.Substring(i, 1));
            char backslash = Convert.ToChar(@"\");
            if (chrWord == backslash)
            {
                word = word.Remove(i, 1);
            }

        }

        return word;           
    }
```

Comment: `String.Replace("\\","")`? . being html, you can "uncode" it, but i can't remember the syntax from the top of my head

Comment: Do you want to remove just the slashes or the entire escape sequence?

Comment: Is the data actually `"\n\t\t\tkegelvrucht\r\n \t\n\t\t"` or is this what the debugger's inspector is telling you? The debugger shows an *escaped* version of the actual string that really does contain tabs, returns and newlines and no actual backslashes. I suspect that `Regex.Replace(data,@"[\r\n\t]+",string.Empty)` would do you just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those backslashes are not in the string, they are just a representation of tabs, carriage returns and line feeds. For example, a string which Visual Studio shows as `\t\t\n\n` is only 4 characters long, not 8.

You can get rid of them just like this:

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = webGet.Load("http://www.willekeurigwoord.nl/");
String word = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1").InnerText;
string fixedWord = word.Trim();
```

`Trim` removes all white spaces that surround your text, including tabs and new lines. If you happen to only want to remove some specific characters, or to remove them in the middle of the string, you need to do something like this:

```
string fixedWord = word.Replace("\t", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Trim();
```

Comment: The correct answer is given by @robert harvey. a simple Trim() in .NET does that without the need of custom code.

Comment: The *"custom code"* is his existing function. I just left surrounding code for clarity.

Comment: Sometimes the solution is for the OP to scrap the code and write the correct one. It is clear by the question that he wants to remove all 'white spaces'. Now your answer looks better. Really. all he wants is a Trim() in the inner text of the h1 node. Also indicate that in C# string is much preferred than String. We should give the strict correct answer so the OP can learn not just an answer that does the job on a already bad code.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `Trim()` on your string:

```
string cleaned = word.Trim();
```

It will remove all leading and trailing *whitespace,* which includes all of the characters you want removed.

Comment: Another example of stackoverflowing. THIS is the correct answer for the OP. All others are 'reinvent the wheel' for not knowing .NET well enough.

Answer (score -2):

Probably a C# String expert will know the answer you are looking for.  But this is a great example of where post C languages make things harder.  **Probably your \ is being taken as an escape character by the compiler, so the code never sees it at run time.**

By the way, "word" is a terrible choice for a label because it is reserved in most languages (meaning a type 16 bits wide or something similar).

In C, you just go through the string character by character and copy each one into a new string based on whether it is or isn't '\';  (I didn't test/debug this, and you need to add bounds checking unless you know the sizes of all the strings.)

```
i = j = 0;

while (strIn[i] != '0') {

    if (strIn[i] != '\') {

        strOut[j++] = strIn[i];

    }

    i++;
}
```

(If that sounds like extra work, know that at run time, your C# is doing that anyway, and hiding the required interaction with the memory manager from you so you don't know why your program runs slowly.)

Comment: Indeed it's just an escape sequence, there's no real backslash in that string. BTW, I would have used a `for` loop for that. ;)

Comment: "for" versus "while" is a matter of personal preferrence, surely.  There was a time when conventional wisdom said that somehow for loops were more fully optimized by the compiler, but I think that was apocryphal from the start.  In this case, since there are two indices behaving differently, I think it makes it more clear that neither are the for index.

I realized after that it would be OK to use the same string for input and output, since the original scenario assumes destruction of the original string.

Comment: Not the correct answer. The code is even wrong in .NET. The answer was given by @robert-harvey.